# How to disable Null and Weak Ciphers on 389-Directory-Server

Tags: centos, encryption, 389-ds, freeipa, ssl

I am running 389-DS on CentOS. Version - '389-ds-base.i686 1.2.11.15-34.el6_5'. Security scans revealed that NullCiphers were found on Port 389 and 636.

I tried to disable them by shutting down DS, editing the 'nsSSL3Ciphers' on all '/etc/dirsrv/slapd-/dse.ldif' files, and starting DS. nsSSL3Ciphers looks like this now -

```
modifyTimestamp: 20140915221826Z
nsSSL3Ciphers: -rsa_null_md5,+rsa_rc4_128_md5,+rsa_rc4_40_md5,+rsa_rc2_40_md5,
 +rsa_des_sha,+rsa_fips_des_sha,+rsa_3des_sha,+rsa_fips_3des_sha,+fortezza,+fo
 rtezza_rc4_128_sha,-fortezza_null,+tls_rsa_export1024_with_rc4_56_sha,+tls_rs
 a_export1024_with_des_cbc_sha
numSubordinates: 1
```

Scans are still showing Null Cipher on those 2 ports.

```
Here is the list of null SSL ciphers supported by the remote server :
  Null Ciphers (no encryption)
    TLSv1
      NULL-SHA                     Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=None                 Mac=SHA1   
The fields above are :
  {OpenSSL ciphername}
Port
389 / tcp / ldap    
636 / tcp / ldap
```

Any ideas on how i can disable these Null ciphers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either fix the ciphers manually as suggested in other answer or, when applicable, simply upgrade to FreeIPA 4.0.3 which fixes the ciphers out of the box ([upstream ticket](https://fedorahosted.org/freeipa/ticket/4395)).

This is what I get with [FreeIPA 4.0.3](http://www.freeipa.org/page/Releases/4.0.3) or 4.1.0 Alpha1:

```
# nmap --script ssl-cert,ssl-enum-ciphers -p 636 `hostname`

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-10-09 01:52 EDT
Nmap scan report for ipa.mkosek-rhel71.test (10.16.78.57)
Host is up (0.000092s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE
636/tcp open  ldapssl
| ssl-cert: Subject: commonName=ipa.mkosek-rhel71.test/organizationName=MKOSEK-RHEL71.TEST
| Issuer: commonName=Certificate Authority/organizationName=MKOSEK-RHEL71.TEST
| Public Key type: rsa
| Public Key bits: 2048
| Not valid before: 2014-10-09T04:52:15+00:00
| Not valid after:  2016-10-09T04:52:15+00:00
| MD5:   0fc7 afd6 343b 9e51 abd0 3ba1 7bde 3c25
|_SHA-1: 246a 02f2 1663 3ca9 e97b cdd4 887e 6e10 7685 5627
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA - strong
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|_  least strength: strong

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.91 seconds
```

Answer (score 3):

You would have to use an LDAP browser such as Apache Directory Studio to modify your configuration or the built-in LDAP utility ldapmodify. I will outline the steps to use ldapmodify, since it will help it make sense if you opt to use a UI tool.

To use ldapmodify, you first create an ldif file that has a specific syntax and then import it. Note that the file has "replace:" sprinkled through it. This specific example is modifying things in cn=encryption,cn=config which you could also view and modify with an LDAP browser. The file would look something like this:

```
dn: cn=encryption,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: nsSSL3
nsSSL3: off
-
replace: nsSSL2
nsSSL2: off
-
replace: nsSSL3Ciphers
nsSSL3Ciphers: nsSSL3Ciphers: -rc4,-rc4export,-rc2,-rc2export,-des,-desede3,-rsa_rc4_128_md5,+rsa_rc4_128_sha,+rsa_3des_sha,-rsa_des_sha,+rsa_fips_3des_sha,+fips_3des_sha,-rsa_fips_des_sha,-fips_des_sha,-rsa_rc4_40_md5,-rsa_rc2_40_md5,-rsa_null_md5,-rsa_null_sha,-tls_rsa_export1024_with_rc4_56_sha,-rsa_rc4_56_sha,-tls_rsa_export1024_with_des_cbc_sha,-rsa_des_56_sha,-fortezza,-fortezza_rc4_128_sha,-fortezza_null,-dhe_dss_des_sha,+dhe_dss_3des_sha,-dhe_rsa_des_sha,+dhe_rsa_3des_sha,+tls_rsa_aes_128_sha,+rsa_aes_128_sha,+tls_dhe_dss_aes_128_sha,+tls_dhe_rsa_aes_128_sha,+tls_rsa_aes_256_sha,+rsa_aes_256_sha,+tls_dhe_dss_aes_256_sha,+tls_dhe_rsa_aes_256_sha,+tls_dhe_dss_1024_rc4_sha,+tls_dhe_dss_rc4_128_sha
```

You would apply the file to your LDAP server like this:

ldapmodify -x -D "cn=directory manager" -W  -f no_null_cipher.ldif

I can't say if these exact commands will work with your specific setup, but this will get you on the right track. Your schema could be different so cn=encryption,cn=config might not be where to make the changes. Just be super careful and if possible test what you are doing thoroughly.